# VB.net not working with SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, easyphp

I have a problem that is eating my brains out.
I have a project with 2 forms : 1 that extracts the data from my database ( name and surname) and another one that checks out if the user input of the user is correct (matching name and surname) . The code for the 1'st form is :
http://pastebin.com/rg5GMuu6

The code for the second is pasted here
I have no idea whatsoever how to repair this error. I've heard something about some sort of an adapter or something......Help
Ty in advance

I am using MySQL (Easy PHP);
Uploading some pics:
[image: error]
[image: sql]
[image: entries]
[image: 1st form works properly]

The first form is working without any problems, the second one gives me this error

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form2

```
Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
Dim strQuery As String = ""
Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim DR As MySqlDataReader


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        'just a message

        MsgBox(" You are searching for the users: " & vbCrLf & "Name: " & TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "Surname: " & TextBox2.Text)


        ' connecting to the database

        dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database = users; Uid = root; Pwd = password")
        strQuery = "SELECT users.name, users.surname FROM users" & _
            " WHERE users.name = @Username AND users.surname = @UserPassword"

        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username ", TextBox1.Text)
        SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", TextBox2.Text)

        'Database open


        dbCon.Open()
        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        If DR.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Not a match", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            MsgBox("You guessed the correct name: " & TextBox1.Text & "and the surname: " & TextBox2.Text)
        End If


        'Close
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Failure to communicate " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Captured all the errors with the debugger
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You've shown us a picture of the error that you created, which isn't *entirely* helpful.  What's the exception which causes that error?  Is there an inner exception?  What line throws the exception?  What is the state of the objects used on that line when it happens?  You need to do at least *some* debugging.

Comment: The code seems to be fine, (a part from the connection not closed in case of exception. Use the Using Statement). Please check the innerexception message. (If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing)

Comment: Did you try to increment the command timeout?

Comment: I didn't how do I do that ?

Comment: SQLCmd.CommandTimeout = 300

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E1SK50M4
Same error

Comment: Please use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the open statement and the execute step by step. When you reach the exception check if there are InnerException messages, tell us also if the error happens on the Open or on the ExecuteReader

Comment: Hey Steve, sorry for such a late response but it was late for me. I have updated the thread, just look upper for the pics. I've used the debugger

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be odd situations with the .AddWithValue statement.  I have found it better to set parameter values with the following two lines of code.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
cmd.Parameters("@UserName").Value = textbox1.text'obviously don't need this if it is an Output Param
```

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking of building the SQL string on the fly and sending that without parameters.  Offending answer has been removed.

Comment: I get the following error : Direction is not a member of Integer

Comment: Change the .INT in the SqlDBType to NVarChar.  If that doesn't work, post the line you are now using.

Comment: @APrough he is using MySql not Sql Server